# which of the following series converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

A. $\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$

B. $\sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty (1.5)^n$

C. $\sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty \frac{4n-1}{5n+1}$

D. $\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty (e)^{-2n}$

So my thinking so far is that everything diverges except D, but I don't know how to specifically show it. The reason I believe so is because as n increases $(1/e^{-2})^n$ will get extremely close to zero meaning that soon you will basically be adding 0 so it will converge. However I don't know if that is correct, or if it is the correct way to think about it. Is there a convergence test that will help me in this case?

Comment: The argument is not sufficient because the behavior is the same in A, which diverges.

Comment: Do you know any convergence tests (e.g. integral test, comparison test, ratio test, root test, etc.)?

Comment: I just looked up the ration test, and i feel like it should help me show that D converges

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. One may recall that each series that converges has its general term tending to $0$, here
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}(1.5)^n=? \qquad \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{4n-1}{5n+1}=?
$$ One may recall that the geometric series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$ is convergent if and only if $|x|<1$. Concerning $A$, one may recall the nature of the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)).

Answer (score 0):

- A   diverges as harmonic
- B   divergent as geometric$(1.5>1)$
- C   the general term doesn't go to zero
- D   converges as geometric$(e^{-2}<1)$.

Comment: Is this a "hint" or a complete solution?

Comment: To me it looks like a solution. And compact enough. Now the OP needs to interpret and understand...